# Close browser/Exit from website Events

Tags: events, browser, web, exit

Nowadays I am creating browser game, using ASPX, CSS and AJAX.
I need to know when the user close the browser or exit from website,
because of these cases for example:

1. if a player opens a game room and than close the browser or exit from the website,
   this room need to be deleted immediately.
2. 2 players are playing in a room, and than one of them leave so the game is finished and the one that stay is the winner. 
   In this case I can use the countdown timer of the players' turns, and when the countdown timer reaches 0 - The other player wins,
   but I prefer that the message will appear as soon as the player left the room,
   its faster, and when the countdown reaches 0 there is 2 possibilities - the player left or the player didn't react in time.

Anyone can tell me how can I know when the user close the browser or exit from my website?
because as far as I know the Session object won't be effective since the Session_End method runs several minutes after the browser is close or the user is AFK,
and I can't let the Session_End close the room for players that are AFK since they are waiting for more players to join, and I need to fire my events immediately.

P.S: I found this method, I don't know if its works but I don't think it will fit my needs because I need the event to fire even when the user move from my site to another website.

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', function() {
    alert('cross-exit tab click AND cross-exit browser click');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onbeforeunload` event fires before the user leaves a page.  This fires when the user closes the browser or tab, or goes to another page, even if that page is on your own website.

Inside the event handler, you'd make a call back to your server saying that the session was closed.  Note that this will have to be an authenticated call with a crumb to avoid an XSRF (ie, player B tricks player A into ending his session).

The only caveat is that it does not work on Opera.  For opera, you could use the `onunload` event, but since this fires when the browser is closed, it's very hard to send anything back to your server in this event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Handling `onbeforeunload` will probably work.